# cert-manager x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, cert-manager

I got an error when try to grpcurl a host running in a kubernetes cluster,

**Failed to dial target host "host.domain.net:443": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

I think is related to the use of a self-signed certificate with cert-manager and is not trusted by a known CA, so I believe I should copy the .cert to /etc/ssl/certs on the target system

The secret related to the certificate is

```
Name:         cert-name.net
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/alt-names: *.net
              cert-manager.io/certificate-name: cert-name.net
              cert-manager.io/common-name: *.net
              cert-manager.io/ip-sans:
              cert-manager.io/issuer-group:
              cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: ClusterIssuer
              cert-manager.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-cf-dns
              cert-manager.io/uri-sans:

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.crt:  3822 bytes
tls.key:  1675 bytes


Name:         regcred
Namespace:    abcd
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

The certificate and the secret

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                                                        READY   SECRET                AGE
istio-system   certificate.cert-manager.io/cert-name.net                                   True    cert-name.net         42h
```

How can I access to the tls.crt in the secret and copy to the path to be a trusted certificate?
Not sure if something else is needed. Additionaly I want to be sure that the host to which the certificate is issued is the same as the host name for the Secret.
thanks!